# Cannot copy the response of a chatbox using Selenium despite trying everything

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

***If the information I am providing is not enough please tell me to provide more***

I am trying to automate a conversation with a chatbot and store the responses. However, Selenium seems to always fail locating the response and returning it.

**This is the HTML code of the chatbox.** I have expanded one of the responses so that you could better understand the HTML. You will see that any `css-liwoqsn` is the element of any response and that `css-v9i7aw` is that of a question. Expanding `css-liwoqsn` until you see the actual response stored in `<p>` and `<ul>`.

```
<div class="MuiBox-root css-v2kfba" data-section="copilot_chat">
    <div class="css-13г9wg5">
        <div class="MuiBox-root css-gajhq5"></div>
        <hr class="MuiDivider-root MuiDivider-fullWidth css-39bb06">
        <div class="css-1a9768g">
            <div class="css-liwoqsn">
                <div class="css-1gprod">
                    <div id="gtiriww2a0souw9" class="css-dcpOta">
                        <div class="MuiBox-root css-107u4gk">
                            <div class="content MuiBox-root css-x97jm9">
                                <div class="mb-2 leading-normal text-black prose prose-p:m-0 prose-a:font-medium prose-a:text-primary prose-a:no-underline hover:prose-a:underline prose-hr:my-3 prose-hr:border-0 prose-hr:border-t prose-hr:border-solid prose-hr:border-t-gray-300" style="font-size: 15px;">
                                    <p> </p>
                                    <ul></ul>
                                    <p> </p>
                                    <ul></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-v9i7aw"></div>
            <div class="css-liwoqsn"></div>
            <div class="css-v9i7aw"></div>
            <div class="css-liwoqsn"></div>
            <div class="css-v9i7aw"></div>
            <div class="css-liwoqsn"></div>
            <div class="css-v9i7aw"></div>
            <div class="css-liwoqsn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additional information regarding the responses' `css-liwoqsn`:

This is the selector:

```
#__next > main > div > span > div > div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-item.MuiGrid-grid-md-5.css-114racd > div > div > div > div.css-1a9768q > div:nth-child(1)
```

This is the `XPath` (new responses always end up on the top `div`):

```
//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]
```

**This is how i have been trying to access the content of the response.**

```
chatbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.MuiInput-input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiInputBase-inputMultiline.css-zvroza')))

        # Initiate conversation with the chatbot and ask each preset question
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        print ("Found textbox successfully")

# ==================== This is the section where i define how to question and retrieve answers from chatbox ============== #

        
        # define function to send message to chatbox
        def send_message(message):
            chatbox.send_keys(message)
            chatbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            print (message)
            time.sleep(10)

        def get_response():
            print("in get response method")
            try:
                chat_messages = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-liwoqsn')))
                latest_chat_message = chat_messages[0]

            except:
                latest_chat_message = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')))

            # Get the response text
            response = latest_chat_message.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.MuiBox-root.css-107u4gk').text
            print(response)
            # Add the response to the responses list
            responses.append(response)
            time.sleep(3) 
            return response

# ==================== This is the section where I question the chatbot using predefined questions ============== #

        for question in questions.values():
                time.sleep(2)
                send_message(question)
                time.sleep(3)
                response = get_response()
                print ("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=")
                responses.append(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

def get_response():
print("in get response method")

```
        # Wait for the chat messages to load
        latest_chat_message = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')))
        # Get the response text
        response = latest_chat_message.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.MuiBox-root.css-107u4gk').text
        # Add the response to the responses list
        time.sleep(3) 
        return response
```